# html input box disappear

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this simple html form. with 3 radio box options.
The last radio box option is 'others'
I want the text box to input other reasons to appear only when then 'other's combo box is selected. is there any way to do that?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="form-group">

        <input type="radio" name="option" value="a"> Missing deadline.<br>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="b"> Unsatisfied with the work.<br>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="c"> No response from Accountant.<br>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="d"> Other reasons. <br>

        <input autofocus type="text" id="reason" name="reason" placeholder="Please key in the reasons.">

    </div>
  <body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery or pure javascript?

Comment: "Pure" JavaScript involves lots of APIs that are not part of the JavaScript programming language :)

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try.

```js
function showTextbox() {
  document.getElementById("reason").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input type="radio" name="option" value="a"> Missing deadline.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="b"> Unsatisfied with the work.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="c"> No response from Accountant.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="d" onclick="showTextbox()"> Other reasons. <br>


    <input autofocus type="text" id="reason" name="reason" placeholder="Please key in the reasons." style="display:none">

  </div>

  <body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using jQuery, by setting an on-change event to the checkbox:

```js
$("#test").change(function(){
  $("#hidden").show()
});
```

```css
#hidden {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click Me
<input type="checkbox" id="test">
<div id="hidden">alec</div>
```